# Is it possible to change Arduino Nano sine wave frequency without using PWM?

Tags: arduino, frequency, waveform, sine

I have a program that generates a sine wave (array with predefined 8 bit values) on an Arduino Nano.

```
    void loop {
      for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        digitalWrite(array[i], D6);
      }
    }
```

The values in the array are hardcoded that means the frequency is predefined as well.
I want have a way to change it. I know that amplifiers, potentiometers and RC filters won't affect the signal's frequency, only amplitude. Is there a way to change the frequency?

Comment: You mention PWM in your title. Why do you think PWM will help you in this situation? Also - can you please add some context about what you want to achieve? Different answers will be appropriate for different situations.

Comment: How exactly are you generating a sine wave with `digitalWrite`?

Comment: The output frequency is proportional to the sample rate. But note that this code does not have good control over the sample rate to begin with. The `for` loop should put out samples at a more-or-less constant rate, assumng that `digitalWrite()` has a constant execution time, and subject to any hardware interrupts that might be occurring. But each time it exits, there will be a significant gap while the `loop()` function returns and then gets called again. You need to start by putting out samples at precise intervals using a hardware timer.

Comment: Re *"I have a program that generates a sine wave"*: No, you haven't. It is a completely bogus program. There are only ***two*** valid values for the output value to [digitalWrite()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/it/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/): "TRUE" and "FALSE". And the value is the ***second*** argument, not the first. This program most likely sets the output value to logical high on a huge number of I/O ports (but behaviour is undefined). The frequency will identical 0 (zero). And the Nano doesn't have a built-in DAC; it is based on the ATmega328.

Comment: It is advised to actually measure on D6. Even a multimeter would reveal it doesn't work (a ***stable*** value of about 2.5 V (the average value of a sine wave) would be expected).

Comment: Surely that should be `analogWrite(D6, array[i]);`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no (reasonable) way to do this without changing the code on the Arduino.

I have a few suggestions for you:

1. "DDS", AKA "Direct Digital Synthesis" 
   Some other answers have already alluded to this common method. Basically, you make a big sine lookup table and then change the frequency by skipping every N samples. Unfortunately, with this technique you can only get frequencies that are integer multiples of your "base wave"'s frequency*. If you use a 100Hz wave as your base wave, this technique will let you generate 100, 200, 300, 400, .... Hz waves, but NOT 101Hz, 150.1Hz, 220Hz or other waves that not integer multiples of your base wave's frequency. If you are a musician, this is the same concept as the [overtone series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(music)) in music. 
   To use this method, you will want to choose the lowest frequency base wave possible. **This can be a problem if you've got limited memory.** To hit all of the freqs you want, you might need a SUPER BIG wave. This is addressed by approach 2:
2. "Wavetable Synthesis" 
   Instead of having just one "base wave", why not have 2, 3, 4, or 10? One of the waves could have f = 55Hz, another f = 58.2Hz, and so on. Each one of these waves takes less memory than a single 0.1Hz "super wave", and you can choose their frequencies so that their harmonics cover the frequencies your interested in. Want to generate a 385Hz sine wave? Use wave #0 with fundamental freq 55Hz and skip 6 samples (use #0, #7, #14, etc...); a 524Hz wave? use wave #1 with fundamental 58.2Hz and skip 8 samples.
3. Just calculate the sine/cos at runtime 
   If you use fixed-point math, you can probably just [calculate sine/cos at runtime](https://www.nullhardware.com/blog/fixed-point-sine-and-cosine-for-embedded-systems/) whenever you need a sample (as long as your sample rate is below ~100kHz). Just change the frequency [the same way you would for a regular sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave#Formulation) (note that this may cause discontinuities when you change freq). This does burn a lot of unnecessary compute, but oh well. Make sure you don't use floating point numbers, or might might burn *too* much compute.
4. Vary your sample rate. 
   Depending on your end application and the wave that you're playing, it might be acceptable to just change how often you update your output. **I suggest avoiding this method.**

Doing this in a computationally efficient way is an interesting problem with its own small body of literature, **especially** if you start looking at non-sine waves. [Alias-Free Digital Synthesis of Classic Analog Waveforms](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Estilti/papers/blit.pdf) is a starting point.

* This is a white lie. You can in fact get arbitrarily good frequency resolution using this method with some fixed-point math tricks (i.e. track wave phase with an N-bit counter but only use the top M bits to index your wave table). You need to watch out when doing this; this always introduces non-harmonic distortion. If your application is really sensitive to such distortion and you want to use this method anyways, you need to find a way to mitigate the effects.

Comment: DDS is **not** confined to just integer multiples of the "base frequency". The DDS phase accumulator can have an arbitrary number of bits, giving arbitrary frequency resolution. You simply use the upper N bits (8 in the OP's example) of the phase accumulator to address the wave table.

Comment: Sure, but that will introduce non-harmonic distortion. Based on the asker's writing style, I imagine that they won't know where non-harmonic distortion is coming from or how to fix it if they go that route.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for the feedback; I've added further detail to my answer to cover the extra info you're describing. Keep in mind that the more bits you chop off, the worse your distortion will be.

Comment: Writing style?!? The OP is using an 8-bit index and 8-bit data and they're using a software loop to control the sample rate. They never mention distortion; it doesn't seem to me that they're too concerned about it. In any case, using integer DDS with N = any number other than powers of 2 already introduces "non-harmonic distortion".

Answer (score 5):

To double the frequency, use every second sample in the lookup table at the same sampling frequency.

To triple the frequency, use every third sample in the lookup table at the same sampling frequency.

etc.

This is the way DDS does it.

The idea is that this technique keeps the sampling frequency constant and, if I remember rightly, the advantage of that is that the cut-off frequency of the reconstruction filter can be kept constant and doesn't need to be varied.

If you were to just step through the complete table at different rates then the sampling frequency would be varying.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is. Run the table entries at double speed or at half the speed for twice or half the frequency. You may want to check out DDS techniques how to generate arbitrary frequencies.

Comment: DDS = [direct digital synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesis)

Comment: Double the speed of 0 Hz is still 0 Hz. The question might be a troll question.